# Constrained extrema of $P=x^3+8y^3-3xy$

Tags: real-analysis

With $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x^2+4y^3=2$.
 Find the Min and Max of $P=x^3+8y^3-3xy$

Answer (score 2):

One can use Lagrange multipliers to tackle constrained max/min problems.

But before you do, note that there is **no** minimum. For we can take $y$ very large negative, and then to satisfy $x^2=2-4y^3$, we can take $x$ large positive **or negative**.

But if $x$ and $y$ are large negative, then so is $x^3+8y^3-3xy$.

There is also **no** maximum. The idea is much the same. Pick $y$ large negative, for concreteness say $-100$. Then to satisfy the constraint, we can take $x\approx 2000$. But then $x^3\approx 8\times 10^9$. Note that $8y^3$, though negative, has much smaller absolute value than $x^3$. And the term $-3xy$, being positive, only increases things. One can use the same argument to show, more formally, that for every $B$ there exist $x,y$ that satisfy the constraint and such that $x^3+8y^3-3xy\gt B$.

**Remark:** If we make the restriction that $x$ and $y$ are $\ge 0$ and satisfy the constraint, then there is a max and a min.

Comment: Can you write more details?

Comment: Pick $y=-100$. Then $x\approx -2000$ satisfies the constraint. It follows that $x^3+8y^3\lt -8\times 10^9$. By picking $y$ and $x$ even larger negative, we can make $x^3+8y^3-3xy$ even larger negative.  By the way, we can also get arbitrarily large positive. I will change the answer to reflect that, so that you will not try to use max/min machinery.